# TTL to NIM logic translation Logic Gate Issue

Tags: transistors, ttl, logic-level

[NIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Instrumentation_Module) is a standard used in nuclear physics. I'm facing an issue with a logic gate being used in my TTL to NIM translation circuit, and I'm not sure what is entirely wrong with it. For a little background, I'm trying to replicate a TTL to NIM logic translation circuit as demonstrated in a reference schematic linked below, but I'm having some issues regarding a specific part of the circuit, specifically the logic gate.

[Here's a link to my reference schematic, but if you prefer, I'll draw out my circuit below.](https://www.ohwr.org/project/conv-ttl-nim-3i-30o/blob/master/trunk/documentation/references/TTL_NIM%20user%20manual_v10.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKazfN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's a little modified from the original circuit with the addition of a pull-down resistor at my TTL logic input at the gate as well as using 5 pF capacitors instead of 3.3p, but otherwise, the rest are the same.

The original schematic used an XOR gate, and it seems to be the F86 XOR gate. I used the 74LS386 quad dual-input XOR gate to substitute for it, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Setting one input to ground, I used a switch to set the other input to 3.3 V for the TTL high input (and when the switch is open, a pull-down resistor for that input pulls it down to 0 volts for logic 0). The output of the gate goes to the rest of the circuit, which should produce a NIM-logic current signal (0 mA for logic 0, -15 mA for logic 1). However, somehow, my XOR gate output doesn't change at all, and the NIM-logic stays constant at -15 mA whether or not my input switch is closed (while the output of the logic gate is between -0.5 and -0.6 V). This behavior also occurs when a gate input is set to VCC (+5V).

Seeing as how this is not behaving correctly, I swapped out the IC with the DM7404N hex inverter IC. Logically, it should behave as if one of the XOR inputs is set to VCC, logic high. Swapping it out and putting a pull-down resistor at the input, the circuit behaves exactly as I hoped it would. The output of the inverter goes from 0.7 V to 3.4V depending on the input, and the NIM current correctly goes from -15 mA to 0. Seeing as how the circuit works with the inverter and not with the XOR gate, I was wondering what could be the reason why? I thought that perhaps the inverter circuit is more simple and allows for larger output current than the XOR gate, but I wonder if that is truly the case?

To be fair, there have been instances where using the XOR gate gives the correct intended result, but this doesn't seem to be consistent anymore. Whereas with the inverter replacing the XOR gate, it seems to work all the time.

EDIT: After reading the comments, I thought to try to use a different XOR gate of a different technology type, specifically the MC14507, the CD4030AY, and the SCC4070BE. I did some research and found that these gates are based on MOS technology which should allow for more current flow, and that seems to be the case. The NIM logic signal switches consistently, so is it safe to assume that all my problems are just using the LS XOR gate?

Comment: Could it be the poor drive current levels of the LS family?

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for your reply. I had a feeling that it might be the case according to the datasheet (LS386 gives out 8 mA where DM7404 gives out 16 mA), but I don't have a non-LS family XOR gate to test with.

Comment: @user101402 you are reading the data sheets incorrectly. When driving a high logic level, the LS family can only muster 0.4 mA whereas other logic families can provide much more umph.

Comment: @Andyaka Can you please explain to me how I'm misreading the datasheets? According to my datasheet for the LS86A, it says that the low-level output current can go up to 8 mA maximum.

Comment: But you're using the high-level output to source current to Q1. 11V / 4.2k = 2.62 mA, plus whatever current Q1's base requires. You could try increasing the values of R2 and R3 by an order of magnitude, to 20k and 22k, respectively.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but doing so still results in the same outcome as before, with the current not changing at all from -15.2 to -15.4 mA, hardly enough to be considered acceptable. With the inverter, it made logic 0 worse, being at -3 mA instead of 0.4 uA.

Comment: The drive capability (high output) for the 74LS386 is 0.4mA max (for the old Mot-SPS part). The 74F86 is 1mA max; a lot of difference. Try pulling more out of the LS part and the output voltage will simply drop due to the effective output resistance in the high state. Datasheets: https://docs.isy.liu.se/pub/VanHeden/DataSheets/sn74ls386.pdf and https://scientific-solutions.com/surplus/parts/938511/74f86.pdf

Comment: @PeterSmith One problem I'm seeing in my tests with the XOR gate is that the output voltage remains relatively low at -0.5 V regardless of the inputs (with one input directly wired to ground), whereas with the inverter, it switches between 300 mV and 3.5 V depending on the input.

Comment: @user101402 - it is quite possible that the initial apparent overload has fried the part.

Comment: @PeterSmith Testing the gate independently showed that it still worked as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how that worked even with the original 'F86 gate — it has a specified maximum I<sub>OH</sub> of -1 mA.

In any case, I would recommend ditching the gate altogether and using another differential amplifier for input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNo8Ah.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q2, R3 and R4 establish the switching threshold for the TTL input. The rest of the circuit is the same as your reference.

If you still want switchable polarity, connect the 'x86 gate to the TTL in shown here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If you don't mind me saying, I found some CMOS-based XOR gates, and replacing the 74LS386 with them seems to make the original circuit switch properly now. I thought that using CMOS-based gates would allow for more current drive in this case. Regarding your circuit that you posted, why do you recommend the use of a diff. amp. here with the additional transistors? It seems that you would need to add more voltage biases (with the +- 2V), so what kind of advantages would this offer?

Comment: It's conservative design, since I don't know how accurately you need to adhere to the TTL interface specification. Also, keeping all of the transistors out of saturation (although this design doesn't completely succeed at that) keeps the switching speeds as fast as possible. Again, I couldn't know how much you depend on that. If you're happy with a CMOS gate, then obviously, neither of these things was important to you.